# How should I build an age verification form with php session?

Tags: php, verification

I need what seems simple to me, but I can't seem to find it online.

I need a user to enter their birthday and for the action on a form to be effected one way or the other. I would also like a session to be set but thats optional.

I know that age verification is lame but its an alcohol company and it has to be there.

I am good with html/css but not stellar with jquery or php...

Thanks so much

Comment: [`mktime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) may be useful; I would recommend avoiding your verification in JavaScript or jQuery because those run on the client, and (a) not all clients support JavaScript (b) the end result would be a `1` or `0` to your server software, which is pretty useless for audit logs. :)

Comment: This is for a basic page on a mobile site... I am open to php but I need to to be a small script either way

Answer (score 0):

The most entertaining age verification I ever saw was the first [*Leisure Suit Larry*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leisure_Suit_Larry), a series of primitive graphical adventure games.  It would ask culturally-based questions that would be instantly known to older players, but kids would not (usually) have a clue.  Like:

> John, Paul, George, and
>   a) Joseph
>   b) Samuel
>   c) Ringo
>   d) Malcom

To successfully enter the game, a potential player has to answer three such questions correctly.  It would pick the three questions at random out of a database of maybe 25.

Obviously, this does not directly answer the question, but perhaps it will inspire a more creative solution than asking a birthday.  (Like that could not be circumvented.)

Comment: It would be interesting to see on websites that use this form of verification, just how many birthdays are on the 1st of January with assorted year ranges well before great depression!

Comment: That does sound funny, but again the federal gov't in the US requires this step for liquor companies.